# No primary or single public constructor found for enum

Tags: spring, jackson, thymeleaf

I keep on struggling with reactive Thymeleaf and now Im stuck into IllegasStateException after passing Enum through @ModelAttribute:

```
   @PostMapping("/lvl")
    public Mono<String> getAllByLvl(@ModelAttribute Level level, Model model) {
        log.info(" level is: " +level);
        return Mono.just(model)
                .flatMap(m -> {
                    m.addAttribute("skill",new Skill());
                    m.addAttribute("skills",new ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable(service.findAllByLevel(level)));
                    return Mono.just(TEMPLATE);
                });
    }
```

enum Level:

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public enum Level {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D;

}
```

form for method:

```html
  <div>
        <h4>filter by lvl</h4>
        <form th:action="@{/skill/lvl}" th:object="${skill}" method="post">
            <select>
                <option value ="${skill.level}">A</option>
                <option value ="${skill.level}">B</option>
                <option value ="${skill.level}">C</option>
                <option value ="${skill.level}">D</option>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </select>

        </form>
    </div>
```

parent entity for the enum:

```
@Data
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Skill implements Persistable<UUID> {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    @Column("skill_name")
    private String name;
    private Level level;
    private Priority priority;
    @Column("skill_group_name")
    private String skillGroupName;

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        boolean result = Objects.isNull(id);
        this.id = result ? UUID.randomUUID() : this.id;
        return result;
    }
```

and it falls with

> Blockquote java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single public constructor found for class com.gmail.qwertygoog.roadmap.model.Level - and no default constructor found either
> at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getResolvableConstructor(BeanUtils.java:250) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
> Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:

So, it seems that enum has all possible constructors, but jackson  couldnot deserialize it properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the lombok annotations on the enum those aren't needed. Another issue I see with your code is your `isNew` method. It is a getter with a side-effect of assigning an id, so after the first call to this method it isn't new anymore?

Comment: Correct, it's due to persisting r2dbc purpose here.

Comment: After removing lombok, still the same:" No primary or single public constructor found for class com.***.model.Level - and no default constructor found either
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getResolvableConstructor"

Comment: It is a bit weird to use an enum as a model attribute. You should be using a `Skill` rather than the `level` and should bind the select to the `level` field of the `Skill` using `th:field`.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums

Something like below

```
public enum Level {
    A ("A"),
    B ("B"),
    C ("C"),
    D ("D");

private String level;

    private Level(String level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

}
```